Building and structure
If the foundation and outer wall of a co-op is deemed to be compromised and the tenants are unable to live in a unit, who holds liability for the cost of relocating?

This would depend to a great extent on the governing documents of the co-op (as well as the cause of the problem and the insurance policies in force), so it is difficult to provide an answer without more details or clarification. Also, the law wouldn't necessary be the same in all places. The law might be different, for example, in Vancouver and New York City.

But are they tenants, or co-owners? i.e. what are the options for the "who" that holds liability? Because as Ohwilleke pointed out, it depends on how the Co-op is structured, and who actually owns the building... "Co-op" implies joint ownership, but there's not enough information given to answer.
